# JSON Schema validation using draft V7

Tags: json

I am trying to write a schema for my JSON file, one of filed shoud be either one of true or false or null

Is there any type which I can use to address above? I am using below types but it seems it doesn't work my schema evaluator

```
"my_column":
type :{
enum:["true","false","null"]
}
```

Can someone gives me any hint?

Comment: try `true` instead of `"true"`, `false` instead of `"false"` and `null` instead of `"null"`

Comment: Does not solve, the same error.